# Pylint: Unexpected Indent error -- for loop

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I have tried several different "styles" of indentation, but VSCode insists that there is an Indentation error around line 70.

For the record - the identifier statement, and all below, are indented in IDE.

```
for node in nodes:
identifier = node['id']
group = node['group']
# Checking if the node is immediately related to the viewer
if (group == viewer_group):
    note = {'source': identifier,
```

VSCode Snapshot:
[image: VSCode Snapshot]

Comment: *"different "styles" of indentation"*..? There should an indentation after `for ...:`.

Comment: What is line 70?

Comment: The "for" statement is line 70. In VSCODE/ IDLE all statements lineup under "node" (1 tab indent)

Comment: Example of the syntax here https://wiki.python.org/moin/ForLoop. You can't really say what belongs in the `for` loop without proper indentation.

Comment: "For the record - the identifier statement, and all below, are indented in IDE." - and why you haven't reproduced that here in your question?

Comment: @ipaleka pasting the code into the form altered the formatting -- please reference the screenshot

Comment: Just put 8 spaces for indented lines next time. Your problem with indentation is above your for loop and your linter points at the line where it ended searching. Provide that part of your code or simply check it by yourself.

Comment: What happens if you delete all the code you are sharing and just type `print()`? Is there a complaint then? What about when you type `from node in nodes: pass`? Without a complete snapshot of all the code and the exact error it's hard to tell (otherwise chances are you have mixed tabs and spaces (`"editor.renderWhitespace": true` will turn that on).

Answer (score 2):

An indent is needed after the for until the end of the loop

```
for node in nodes:
    identifier = node['id']
    group = node['group']
    # Checking if the node is immediately related to the viewer
    if (group == viewer_group):
        note = {'source': identifier, 

# code after loop
...
```

Comment: Also may want to note that is important to be consistent. I.e. either use tabs or use spaces for the indentation but don't use both. I would personally recommend using 4 spaces for indentation.